# Android: reducing code repetition for EditText

Tags: android

Recently I am learning to create Android apps, and I made a simple input form app as practice. I have to process multiple `EditText` fields at once in several functions, so I put `EditText` items into a Java array so I do not have to repeat the same code over and over again. Excerpt of code:

```
    public void resetFields(View view){
        EditText name = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        EditText age = findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        EditText address = findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        EditText phone = findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNumber);
        EditText[] fields = {name, age, address, phone};
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
            fields[i].setText("");
        }
    }
```

Doing so for multiple functions proved to be troublesome because I have to repeat the process, and creates tons of identical code, making it hard to sort out the mess.

I wanted to put them in as class variables for the activity to save some time, but when I do so I cannot run the app. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Post error logs. Are you saying there are several methods in the same activity where you want to manipulate the EditTexts but the app is crashing?

Comment: Make them class variables like you tried, but set their initial values to null and do all the `findViewById` in `onCreate()`. Or better yet, use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: @SABANTO Yes. And if I put them as private class variables the app cannot be installed on the AVD.

Comment: @ZheShengLim where are you initializing, as Tenfour04 pointed out, it needs to be when they are accessible i.e. after onCreate.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I got that fixed now. Thanks.